# Errors in percentage and root mean square error

Tags: mathematical-statistics, prediction, error, percentage

The unit of root mean square error is the same as the unit of the population.
Since I want to show the validity of my prediction model ( by comparing the predicted values and actual ones), I need to show the errors in percentage, but logically I can't find a relation between RMSE and percentage. Are there any methods for calculating errors in percentage?

Or any other methods to show RMSE as a percentage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since I want to show the validity of my prediction model ( by comparing the predicted values and actual ones), I need to show the errors in percentage

There is no logical connection between *showing the validity of a predicton model* and using *percentage errors*.

Percentage errors are one very specific loss function. There are others. A point (!) prediction method may perform better than a different one on percentage errors, but it may be the other way around for other loss functions, like the MSE.

Which loss function is most appropriate depends on what you want to do with the point prediction, i.e., which functional of the future density you want to elicit. I have written more about this in a recent short paper ([Kolassa, 2020, *IJF*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207019301359)). You may also be interested in [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)